# Docusaurus multi-instances and multi-searchs

Tags: javascript, documentation, algolia, docusaurus, typesense

I'm trying to integrate 3 documentation individually into a single docusaurus app.

in case of creating multiple instances of the same app, I managed to solve it. The biggest problem is thinking about how to integrate 3 different search bars for each of them with Algolia or Typesense, is this possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.